# is there a powershell to see all the site collection for a given conent db

Tags: powershell

Get-SpSite

I am trying to find powershell syntax to list all the site collection for a given content database. Is there 1 line syntax for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ContentDatabase parameter of [Get-SPSite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607950.aspx)

```
Get-SPSite -ContentDatabase <guid or database name>
```